# How to check if a folder exists using PHP

Tags: php, file-io, directory

I have this code to check if a folder exists using PHP and it works correctly with xampp in windows, but when I try to move that page to a server, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

> ```
>   function validate (&$valores, &$errores, $campo, $carpeta)
>     {
>     $valores [$campo] = $carpeta;
>             if ((file_exists($carpeta) && is_dir($carpeta))==false)
>             {
>                     $errores[$campo] = true;                   
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                     $errores[$campo] = false;
>             }
>     }
> ```

There is an alternative to the code that I'm doing?

Comment: Generally this type of problem is due to a "case sensitivity" issue.

Comment: also it could be pathing problem, just check if `$carpeta` is really the folder you are looking for using `echo`

Comment: define "it doesn't work". what folders do you have, what errors are you getting, what did you echo/var_dump/step-trough, what did you find out, etc

Comment: In windows I check if exists C:\data, and in my server if exists /data.

Comment: Could be a permissions problem? How could check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I added to PHP open_basedir folders and files I wanted to change, and then with Filezilla I've modified the read / write permission and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php and check for false.

Comment: I've tried this and I also have noticed that the name that I'm using is exactly that I'm looking for and everything is right. But the code doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should operate fine on both platforms, so its not this issue.

Usually, such problem due to the `naming system`. The linux based OS using strict case sensitive naming system.

So try to fix that.

Comment: @edsonlp1, It does not matter if they are correct, their cases have to be exactly the same. The whole path, combined with Direcotories and files.

Comment: I've done echo ($carpeta), and returns to me the whole path. Of course, is right. But, when evaluates file_exists returns to me false

Comment: @edsonlp1, That is not the case here, although the `$carpeta` might return the whole path. Those file and directory are not the same on the file system.